# How to create setup/installer for my Python project which has dependencies?

Tags: python, linux

I have created a simple software with GUI. It has several source files. I can run the project in my editor. I think it is ready for the 1.0 release. But I don't know how to create a setup/installer for my software.

The source is in python. Environment is Linux(Ubuntu). I used an external library which does not come with standard Python library. How can I create the installer, so that I just distribute the source code in the tar file. And the user installs the software on his machine(Linux) by running a setup/installer file?

**Please note**: When the setup is run, it should automatically take care of the dependencies.**(Also, I don't want to build an executable for distribution.)**
Something similar to what happens when I type:

**sudo apt-get install XXXX**

Comment: take a look [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-package-and-distribute-python-applications)

Comment: @Mauro that looks like exactly what I need. Thanks, I will get back if I face any issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at

- setuptools
- distutils

These are classical tools for python packaging

Comment: A little more information on the topic would be appreciated. I am kind of a noob in this area. I searched but the documentation seemed too overwhelming for me.
can you give a short demo or high level steps please?